# Generic Behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, generics, behavior

I would like create generic behavior. My problem is generic declaration in XAML.

```
    public class GenericBehavior<T> : Behavior<DataGrid>
        where T : class 
    {
    }
```

I can’t use [x:TypeArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee956431%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) because I don’t have loose XAML file.

> In WPF and when targeting .NET Framework 4, you can use XAML 2009
>   features together with x:TypeArguments but only for loose XAML (XAML
>   that is not markup-compiled). Markup-compiled XAML for WPF and the
>   BAML form of XAML do not currently support the XAML 2009 keywords and
>   features

I found some [workaround](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/06/limitedgenericssupportinxaml.aspx) with MarkupExtension but with Behaviors not work.

In my current solution [I attach behavior in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422385/attach-behavior-in-code-behind).

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need to use generic behaviors? Adding a type parameter could be a workaround?

Comment: @Didier: I would like to know if it is possible do in XAML without complicated workaround.

Comment: A simpler workaround might be to create a concrete, non-generic subclass for every concrete instance of `T` that you want to use, i.e., `public class FooBehavior : GenericBehavior<Foo> {}`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the generic Behavior inside your view model then inject it to your control using attached properties.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Behavior MyBehavior
    { 
        get 
        {
            return new GenericBehavior<SomeType>();
        } 
    }
}

public class AttachedBehaviors
{
    public static Behavior GetBehavior(DependencyObject sender) => (Behavior)sender.GetValue(BehaviorProperty);
    public static void SetBehavior(DependencyObject sender, Behavior value) => sender.SetValue(BehaviorProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BehaviorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Behavior", typeof(Behavior), typeof(AttachedBehaviors),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(BehaviorChanged)));

    private static void BehaviorChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is FrameworkElement elem)
        {
            if (e.NewValue is Behavior behavior)
            {
                BehaviorCollection Behaviors = Interaction.GetBehaviors(elem);
                Behaviors.Add(behavior);
            }
        }
    }

}

public class GenericBehavior<T> : Behavior<DataGrid> where T : class
{
    public T TestValue { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
    }
}
```

now you can use it like this

```
<DataGrid local:AttachedBehaviors.Behavior="{Binding MyBehavior}" > 
</DataGrid>
```

PS: you just need to install `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` NuGet package.