# Adding interaction behaviour dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've the following code in my MainWindow.xaml file:

```
<dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <dx:DXSplashScreenService SplashScreenType="local:LoadingSplashScreen" ShowSplashScreenOnLoading="True"/>
</dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I need to be able to add this code dynamically from codebehind(MainWindow.xaml.cs). Is this possible?

Do I need to use `Interaction.GetBehaviors(yourElementName).Add(behavior)`??

Thanks.

Comment: If you thought that code would work, why haven't you just tried it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422385/attach-behavior-in-code-behind

Answer (score 0):

You can add like,

```
var splashScreenService = new DevExpress.Xpf.Core.DXSplashScreenService 
                              { 
                                  SplashScreenType = typeof(LoadingSplashScreen), 
                                  ShowSplashScreenOnLoading = true 
                              };
DevExpress.Mvvm.UI.Interactivity.Interaction.GetBehaviors(yourElement).Add(splashScreenService);
```